# Change double precision of data file

Tags: linux, awk, double, precision, data-files

I have one hundred files with three fields. Each one looks like this (with more lines) :

```
#time data1 data2
20 1.9864547484940e+01 -3.96363547484940e+01
40 2.164547484949e+01 -3.2363547477060e+01 
60 1.9800047484940e+02 -4.06363547484940e+02
…
```

They are heavy and some of them take up to 1.5G. I would like to reduce their size by saving the two last columns with a lower double precision and deleting the `e+0?` item. For example, I would like to convert the four lines above to :

```
#time data1 data2
20 19.865 -39.636
40 21.645 -32.364
60 198.00 -406.36
…
```

I googled and came across the `CONVFMT` option of `awk`. But I don't know how to use it since I'm really not a pro of awk. Is this the right tool to use in my case ? If so, how should I use it ?

I also thought of writing a C++ script, but a direct command line would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use awk's `printf` function:

```
awk 'NR==1;NR>1{printf "%d %.3f %.3f\n", $1, $2, $3}' file
```

The above command outputs:

```
#time data1 data2
20 19.865 -39.636
40 21.645 -32.364
60 198.000 -406.364
```

Short explanation:

`NR==1` evaluates to `true` if we are on the first line (*NR* == number of record). If a condition is not followed by an action (between `{}`) awk simply prints the line, in this case the headers.

`NR>1` evaluates to `true` on all other lines except the first line of input. It is followed by an action, which uses `printf` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: great ! only one thing : this seems to convert headers too. How can I tell awk to not consider them ?

Comment: Is NR incremented after the semicolon, so that  `NR>1` evaluate to true ?

Comment: No, the whole command is executed *per line*, meaning on every line of input. On the first line, the `NR==1` before the `;` becomes `true` on remaining lines the `NR>1` becomes `true`.

Comment: Is it possible to evaluate if a line is a header by making an equality test on strings ? Indeed, I have headers not only at the very first line.

Comment: Does a header line always starts with `#` ?

Comment: yes they all do, so how to test with awk if first character is '#' ?

Comment: Replace `NR==1` by `/^#/`

Answer (score 0):

You could use coreutils:

```
head -n1 infile; tail -n+2 infile | while read n1 n2 n3; do printf "%d %.3f %.3f\n" $n1 $n2 $n3; done
```

Output:

```
#time data1 data2
20 19.865 -39.636
40 21.645 -32.364
60 198.000 -406.364
```